# using alloc and init

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, initialization, allocation

We know about the complete pattern of alloc/init that alloc and init must be combined.

```
NSObject *myObj = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

1- init method receives the object from another source(not from a alloc,new,copy or alike or retained) so according to the fundamental memory management rule its not the owner and it must not **release** it. However, **"Allocating and Initializing Objects / The Returned Object"** article says that **init** could **free** the receiver.

**How could this be possible when its against the fundamental rule?**

2- Also, from the same article, init could return another object or nil. So, in this case, when we use the complete pattern of alloc/init, we could not release the object returned by alloc but we could only release the object returned from init and, init releases the object it received from alloc instead of us.

But **init** is not a alloc,new,copy or alike method so we must **not release** the object returned from it as it does not give us the ownership of object.

**How could we release the object returned from init although this is against the fundamental rule?**

3- Or, to adhere to the last paragraph of the same article, **must we accept init method as a special case and use alloc/init pattern as an exception to the fundamental rule?**

> **Memory Management Fundamental Rule:**
>
> - You only release or autorelease objects you own.
>
>   - You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy), or if you send it a retain message.
>   - You use release or autorelease to relinquish ownership of an object. autorelease just means “send a release message in the future” (to understand when this will be, see “Autorelease Pools”).
>       http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html
>
> **Allocating and Initializing Objects / The Returned Object:**
>
> However, in some cases, this responsibility can mean returning a different object than the receiver. For example, if a class keeps a list of named objects, it might provide an initWithName: method to initialize new instances. If there can be no more than one object per name, initWithName: might refuse to assign the same name to two objects. When asked to assign a new instance a name that’s already being used by another object, **it might free the newly allocated instance and return the other object**—thus ensuring the uniqueness of the name while at the same time providing what was asked for, an instance with the requested name.
>
> In a few cases, it might be impossible for an init... method to do what it’s asked to do. For example, an initFromFile: method might get the data it needs from a file passed as an argument. If the file name it’s passed doesn’t correspond to an actual file, it won’t be able to complete the initialization. In such a case, **the init... method could free the receiver and return nil**, indicating that the requested object can’t be created.
>
> Because an init... *method might return an object other than the newly allocated receiver, or even return nil*, **it’s important that programs use the value returned by the initialization method, not just that returned by alloc or allocWithZone:.** The following code is very dangerous, since it ignores the return of init.
>
> ```
> id anObject = [SomeClass alloc];
> [anObject init];
> [anObject someOtherMessage];
> ```
>
> Instead, to safely initialize an object, you should combine allocation and initialization messages in one line of code.
>
> ```
> id anObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
> [anObject someOtherMessage];
> ```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocAllocInit.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `init` method doesn't receive the object; the object receives the `init` message. The object does not possess itself; rather, it always knows about itself (through the implicit `self` argument in every message).

You're right that the object does not own itself, though. If `alloc` and `init` were fused in a single `new` method, that method would be its own (`super`) caller, so it would own the object (until it returns) and so be unquestionably right in releasing it. Since they are separate, and `init` is not the caller of `alloc`, you're right that it does not own the object, so you are right to question this practice.

This is one of the few cases where it's OK for one object to release an object (in this case, itself) on behalf of another. The alternative is not to release it, which, if you're going to either return `nil` or throw an exception, will be a leak.

In general, anytime you have an object retain or release itself, you should feel dirty. *In this specific case*, it's OK, because you are preventing a bug (a leak) rather than probably creating one.

> 2- Also, from the same article, init could return another object or nil. So, in this case, when we use the complete pattern of alloc/init, we could not release the object returned by alloc but we could only release the object returned from init and, init releases the object it received from alloc instead of us.
>
> But init is not a alloc,new,copy or alike method so we must not release the object returned from it as it does not give us the ownership of object.

As `init` releases the old object on behalf of its caller, if it creates a new object, it does that on behalf of its caller. The caller does own the substitute object that `init` creates or retrieves for it.

As a corollary to this, if `init` retrieves a previously existing object, it must retain that, so that the caller will own it.

Again examining the hypothetical* `new` method, it would also need to both release the old object and create (owningly) or retain the substitute.

In all of these cases, it's `init` acting on behalf of its caller. It's normally dodgy for one method to do another's memory management, but for these cases, `init` doing it on behalf of its caller is necessary.

*The `new` method does exist, but simply sends `alloc` and `init`, so there's no need to implement it separately.

Comment: great explanation! thanks. so, init is accepted as a special case, otherwise, i may declare a prepareIt to substitute init but does not specify this and, others call it with memory management rules in mind and introduce bugs.

Comment: after reading Sean U's statement i conclude that init is not a special case. so could we generalize the following: "while an object's instance method is running its the owner of the object and it could do anything with it(de-allocate,re-allocate) so it acts on behalf of its caller and could return another instance or nil."

Comment: There is no “an object's instance method”. Every instance of NSObject or any subclass of NSObject has many instance methods. `init` is not the owner of the object; the owner of the object is *another object*. The initializer (`init` or some other `init…` method) implementation should act on behalf of that owner.

Comment: so i am confused about "that method would be its own (super) caller" in your answer. so you mean calling the super's designated initializer?

Comment: No, I mean calling the hypothetical fused-together `new` method that both creates and initializes the object. Yes, I mean calling up to `super`—the subclass implementation is the superclass implementation's caller. The object that creates the new object is the new object's owner; in a world where separate `alloc` and `init` don't exist, the class you send the `new` message to would be the owner of the new object until it returns the object and that ownership to you. This doesn't apply in our world because `init` doesn't call `alloc`.

Answer (score 3):

If initialization fails for some reason and must return null, then you must release the object in order to avoid leaking memory.

Similarly, init may decide to swap in a different object and return it - in that case you must also release the object in order to avoid leaking memory.

In both cases it's necessary because the original object isn't being returned by init, and will be orphaned after the method returns.  Alloc has automatically retained the object, so if you don't release it its retain count will be stuck at 1 forever.

Comment: that's right but this is against memory management rules. why not Apple clearly specify this as a special case against memory management rules?

Comment: Think of it this way:  While init is running, init *is* the object's owner.  It must be, because it's the only thing that has a reference to the object.  The caller will become the owner, but only after init returns and only if init decides to return that object.  Otherwise, init is the only owner it will ever have.

Comment: So becoming owner of the object could be accepted only for init. otherwise, think about this way: we have another instance method, it is the only thing that has a reference to the object so it could release the object but owner may have already autoreleased the object or will release after calling this method. so, any other instance method must not release the object. this is a special case for init, we must accept this as a special case.

Answer (score 1):

[Would another perspective help?] 
The init method (and its siblings initWith... and similar) is a bit of an odd case but is not a special case of memory allocation rules. Init is odd because it has a name that sounds like it is going to change the internals of the instance but in fact it may do more than that (it may substitute some other object and initialize *that* object, for example). The tip-off is in the declaration of init:

```
- (id)  init  // the way it is
```

vs

```
- (void) init  // in some other universe
```

The init method returns an object, so it might have been better named something like 'return an object that is (class-wise) an equivalent object and that has been initialized'. Most methods do not perform this kind of switcheroo, which makes init a bit different/odd.

There is nothing 'magic' about the alloc / init nesting -- it's just the simplest way to handle the fact that the object that you get back from alloc may not be the same object you get back from init. This works perfectly fine:

```
NSSomeClass* s = [NSSomeClass alloc];
s = [s init];  // that 's =' part is really important ;-)
```

and is exactly equivalent to the 'standard' idiom:

```
NSSomeClass* s = [[NSSomeClass alloc] init];
```

This is potentially problematic:

```
NSSomeClass* s = [NSSomeClass alloc]
[s init];   // bad! you ignored the result of init
```

The implementation of an init method must be done particularly carefully when the implementation returns a different object than the one it receives as the incoming 'self'. In such a case the init method takes on the responsibility of memory management of the 'self' object (because it's not going to return that object - so who else could be expected to do the management?)

It's possible to do some pretty ugly trickery, BTW. Don't try this at home!

```
// don't do this!
S* s = [S alloc] 
[s retain]; // needs to survive 2 init's
S* ss = [s init......];  // s.retain goes 2-->1
S* sss = [s init.....];  //  ... goes 1-->0;
```

Doing this is extremely poor practice because it depends on the init..... method always returning a new object (instead of the one it receives). That's an obviously bad assumption!

NOTE that by "a method receiving an object in 'self'" I mean that the method was invoked upon/by an object, and that object is made available by convention through the 'self' pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental rule just doesn't apply in this special situation.

In fact, don't worry about it - unless you plan to do Posing, you won't need to write code that does this, and it will have no impact at all on the code you write.

You should continue to follow the fundamental rule in all your code.

Answer (score 0):

> And thirdly, the code is more what you'd call "guidelines" than actual rules.

(Captain Barbosa)

alloc/init is a bit of a special case.  You have to do the retain/release stuff inside init in such a way that whatever object the caller gets back is owned by the caller and there are no leaks.